# Open some links in IE automatically when IE is not the default browser

Tags: windows-xp, browser, internet-explorer-8

I've set Firefox as my default browser instead of IE. But there are some URLs (Share-point portals), which I would wish to open in IE automatically. These URLs may be clicked from some word documents, email messages etc. How can I do this? I'm using Windows XP, IE8.

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserChooser](http://browserchooser.codeplex.com/) seems to be what you are looking for. Basically, it acts as your default browser and gives you the option to select which browser you want to use.